# Spring WS client sending HTTPS requests

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-security, spring-ws

I implemented a web service that acts both as a server and a client. So, there is another web service that calls my web service and I forward the call to another web service. So, my web service is acting as a middleman. I implemented the web service using Spring-WS, and I chose annotations over XML. So, there is no XML configuration file. When I act as a client and use HTTP to talk to another web service, I get the correct results back. However, I need to make HTTPS requests and I could not find good examples on what needs to be implemented in Spring-WS client. So, if I have to implement this, where should I start with Spring-WS? Are there any good examples/source that I can refer to?

Also, I need to verify that the cert from server is valid. Is there a mechanism in Spring to check if the cert that I get from the server is the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to HTTPS on the client side should be as simple as switching to a https scheme in your URL. By default, the `WebServiceTemplate` supports HTTPS.

As for certificate validation, that is not done by Spring-WS itself, but rather by the underlying HTTP connection library. If, for instance, you are using HTTP Components (i.e. the `HttpComponentsMessageSender`, which I recommend using), [this page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html) seems relevant.